# How to add dropdown-list inside the PHP code?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have attached the code below, from which i need to know how can i add drop-down in it.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Student/Staff</label>
    {!! Form::input('text', 'student_staff', null, array('id' => 'student_staff', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'student_staff', 'tabindex' => 20)) !!}
 </div>
```

Comment: <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Student/Staff</label>
            {!! Form::input('text', 'student_staff', null, array('id' => 'student_staff', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'student_staff', 'tabindex' => 20)) !!}
          </div>

Comment: The above is my complete code..

Answer (score 0):

{!! Form::select('student_staff', ['student' => 'Student','staff' => 'Staff'], null, array('id' => 'student_staff', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'student_staff', 'tabindex' => 20)) !!}

This works for me..